# HTML onClick event handling while document is loading?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am calling the Javascript function while from the HTML `onClick` event. I works fine when the page is loaded but when I click the button while the document is not ready it gives undefined function error in the console.

```
<a onclick="myfunc(params)" href="javascript:void(0)" >Click Me</a>
```

`myfunc` is defined in another js file.

Comment: try moving your script into the head

Comment: @IsmailFarooq yes, but that can slow the page loading speed.

Comment: i think there is no other way. May be you can cache your page that helps you to load page fast see here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the javascript file that contains this function in the head  section of the page. We load javascript files using the script tag and it's render blocking, which means that the required will be loaded first and then this Click Me will load and you can then click on this whenever this link is visisble.

Comment: You can minify the script for page load speed optimization. or you can call the script right before this element. or you can move that specific function into this html file.